Как получить ID пользователя discord который воспользовался tree.command?
@client.tree.command()
async def add_me(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Hi, {interaction.user.id}')

У меня есть вот такой код. Я пытался получить пользовательский ID как только мог, но всегда получал в ответ None. Есть варианты как используя tree.command получить пользовательский идентификатор?

Замени на свой токен и сервер id и проверь этот код, у меня всё работает:
import discord
from discord import app_commands


MY_GUILD = discord.Object(id=0)  # Айди твоего сервера


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *, intents: discord.Intents):
        super().__init__(intents=intents)
        self.tree = app_commands.CommandTree(self)

    async def setup_hook(self):
        self.tree.copy_global_to(guild=MY_GUILD)
        await self.tree.sync(guild=MY_GUILD)


intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = MyClient(intents=intents)

@client.tree.command()
async def add_me(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Hi, <@{interaction.user.id}>')
    

client.run('Твой токен здесь')


Спасибо, но это несколько не то что мне необходимо. Мне нужно получить пользовательский циферный идентификатор, а не ID формата "@", но все равно спасибо
